# Atom sass indentation errors

Tags: sass, indentation, atom-editor

I'm trying to modify a sass file from WordPress but I keep getting indentation errors and I can't figure out why.

I've tried:

1. Auto indent in Atom which doesn't work with sass (it just removes all indentation, this seems to be a bug with no fix so far)
2. The file is seemingly correctly indented with 4 spaces like I also usually use. If I delete the original 4 spaces and re-type them it works. I have tried to find/replace but it doesn't work either. It doesn't matter if I re-type the 4 spaces or just hit tab.
3. I've tried searching online for a solution for about an hour now. If it's already been answered a bunch of times I'm sorry to re-ask the question but I need help finding the answer.

The file has over 2.000 lines and so far I've takes the first 150 lines and tried different ways of re-indenting, but whenever I take a new bite and re-indent manually it just pushes the indentation error to the next original line of code. I really do not want to manually go through the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Going on **a lot** of assumptions for your Settings for Atom, but inside of your Settings look for  `Tab Length` and make sure this is set to 2. Then look at `Tab Type` Change this to `soft`.

I'd also suggest installing [Atom Beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) to clean up your files